# Does “arbitrarily small” mean very close to zero or very negative?

Tags: notation, terminology

In mathematical writing, does “arbitrarily small” mean *very close to zero* (like $0.000001$) or *very negative* (like $-1000000$)?

Are there better phrases to distinguish these two cases?

Comment: Maybe saying "arbitrarily small magnitude" would better indicate numbers that are very close to $0$.

Comment: It means "as small as you want", so yes.

Comment: A question should be readable on its own, not as a continuation of the title. (Edited)

Comment: I think it is better to let the OP edit the question on their own, so I have returned the question to its original state to allow them to do so.

Comment: I'm OK with the edit

Comment: Just wanted to add to the answer below saying "arbitrarily small" is not to be taken to mean any *specific* number. It is essentially to say that the quantity in question is completely negligibly in so much that we may well consider it $0$. Although, when talking about such things rigor is always needed; so I would advise against taking this intuitive description to heart, while at the same time avoiding thinking of an arbitrarily small number as something like $1 \times 10^{-6}$.

Comment: As an interesting aside, it is perfectly acceptable to say $.\bar9 = 1.$

Comment: Usually, this is clear from context. In the case of quantities known to be positive ($\delta$, $\epsilon$), there is no ambiguity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traditionally, it's the first one: "arbitrarily small" means "small in magnitude", close to zero.

I see the logic behind the second interpretation, but numbers like $-10^9$ are normally thought of as *large negative numbers*, so using "small" to describe them is bound to be confusing.

Also on English.SE: [What is an adjective for a very large negative number?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/102351/what-is-an-adjective-for-a-very-large-negative-number)

Answer (score -1):

Usually, "Arbitrarily Close" is used to reference a proximity or distance between two points.  If two points are arbitrarily close, the difference is such that they are all but the same point; they are so close the difference is insignificant - except that they are different.

Comment: The question is about small, not close.

Comment: It would be helpful to stick to terminology of the original question---how is your concept of "arbitrarily close" related to the concept of "arbitrarily small"? Pedantic? Yes, but this seems to be the exact confusion that the OP is having. Also, "arbitrarily close" to what?